# How to change the way a devexpress grid sorts rows

Tags: sorting, devexpress, gridcontrol

I have a devexpress grid control on my screen.  One of the fields in the table is Room number, and is taking in a string (just in case you have room 2A or something like that).  However, when I click the column header (to sort the values in either ascending or descending order), it doesn't work for all the values.  There are blank spaces everywhere, strings are above a room number with 0, the whole thing is a mess.  Is there a way for me to change the way the grid sorts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement custom sorting via the [ColumnView.CustomColumnSort](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_CustomColumnSorttopic) event.
Custom sorting is enabled for the specific column if its [GridColumn.SortMode](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridColumnsGridColumn_SortModetopic) property is set to `ColumnSortMode.Custom`.